# "Use of unresolved identifier" Can't for the life of me figure out what's going on. (Xcode, Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nfc, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

Okay, so I'm playing around with the nfc capabilities on xcode, and potentially writing them. but as I try to move forward, I find that I'm unable to because my "documentTypes." I have made sure that it is set to target the ios platform, I just don't know what to do now.

[image: screenshot of my code]

Comment: What error are you getting? What  is the type of `documentTypes`?

Comment: @Yonat Post your code as code and not as screenshots. Take a look at [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). FYI: I'm not the down-voter.

Comment: The compiler is correct: `documentTypes` is undeclared. Fix that.

Comment: @Yonat my mistake I meant the poster. 

Comment: `documetTypes` is not declared. Seems like this question never needed posting. but can be turned to a useful question if it's changed to being about understanding what Compiler in complaining about.

Comment: @AppleCiderGuy I declared it wrong! Sorry, I don't usually use Xcode. I've also never made an app before! I appreciate your feedback and thank you for leaving a comment :)

Comment: @Frankenstein Thanks so much for the advice! I've never asked a question on stack overflow and I'm a self taught coder. I hope you'll excuse my lack of expertise :)

Answer (score 0):

I can not see any declaration of `documentTypes` in the code screenshot.

You have to pass an array of `documentTypes`. You can use the line below.

```
var docPicker: UIDocumentPickerViewController = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: ["public.text"], inMode: UIDocumentPickerMode.Import)
```